# Error: IOSurface.h not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios9.3, iosurface

xcode still give me error when i try to import IOSurface.
I've tried all possibilities, import framework, link framework on project but xcode still give me error.

Anyone know why?

[image: Screenshot Error]

Thanks to all for any answer

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/iosurface Only available in OSX

Comment: but i have see source which include this

Comment: For iOS? Which one? It seems that's only for OS X, but it could exist (and not public) for jailbreaken devices using private APIs.

Comment: yes, i know is private...
there is one method for extract and use?

Comment: xcode 9 GM same broplem